# xstream - unable to initialize values of custom list element

Tags: java, serialization, collections, null, xstream

I have below Allocation & Charge beans with input XML as -

```
 public class Allocation {
     private Integer allocQty;
     private Double allocPrice;
     private List<Charge> charges;
 }
 public class Charge {
    private String chargeType;
    private String chargeSubType;
 }

<allocation>
    <allocQty />
    <allocPrice />
    <charges>
        <charge>
            <chargeType>A</chargeType>
            <chargeSubType>B</chargeSubType>
        </charge>
        <charge>
            <chargeType>C</chargeType>
            <chargeSubType>D</chargeSubType>
        </charge>
    </charges>
</allocation>
```

Trying with below xstream config gives me TWO elements list of Charge, but those Charge objects have all fields (String) as NULL !!  Am I missing something here ?

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
xstream.ignoreUnknownElements();

xstream.alias("allocation", Allocation.class);
...
xstream.alias("charge", Charge.class);
xstream.addImplicitCollection(Allocation.class, "charges", "charges", Charge.class);
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "implicit collection" XStream means collection of elements without enclosing ("root") element (see [configuration manual](http://xstream.codehaus.org/manual-tweaking-output.html#Configuration_ImplicitCollection)). In your XML `charge` elements *are* enclosed by the `charges` element. Therefore `charges` is NOT implicit collection and `addImplicitCollection` configuration is wrong. So you can either leave XML as is and remove 'addImplicitCollection' invocation or remove `charges` element, like this:

```
<allocation>
    <allocQty />
    <allocPrice />
    <charge>
        <chargeType>A</chargeType>
        <chargeSubType>B</chargeSubType>
    </charge>
    <charge>
        <chargeType>C</chargeType>
        <chargeSubType>D</chargeSubType>
    </charge>
</allocation>
```

(in the later case you also must fix typo: third parameter of `addImplicitCollection` must be `"charge"`, not `"charges"`).

Comment: Thanks Alex .. I realized the same after posting this question.  very explanation for a newbie like me.